# NSNumberformatter displays "HUF" instead of "ft" when trying to format Hungarian currency

Tags: ios, formatting, string-formatting, currency, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying format a number to Hungarian currency format. But for some reason it displays the 3 digit currency code instead of the forint symbol (ft) like so

```
10,00 HUF
```

It seems to work fine for other countries/currencies, for example British pounds is displayed

```
£10.00
```

Here is my code

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
formatter.currencyCode = "HUF"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "hu_HU")
let formattedString = formatter.stringFromNumber(10)
```

Any idea why it behaves like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Hungary simply does not have a currency symbol other than `HUF` for iOS.

```
formatter.internationalCurrencySymbol
formatter.currencySymbol
formatter.currencyCode
```

all output

> "HUF"

Even on the actual device by setting the region you will get that result:

[image]
[image]

Therefore if your really, **really** want to get the [**symbol Ft**](http://www.xe.com/currency/huf-hungarian-forint) you probably have to manually replace it.